Deprecation of typedef does not work on GCC and MSVC (does on Apple Clang) when used as a stream operator argument
In our code we have a class which has an alias (typedef), and we are trying to deprecate that alias. We do not want to deprecate the original class (really, the class with its new name). We want to deprecate only the alias (the old name).
The C++14 spec indicates that this should be very simple:
[[deprecated]] typedef AliasName RealName;

We were confused that this was working for us on Apple Clang (16) but was not working on GCC (8, 11) or MSVC (VS 2022). Then, after much experimentation, we realize it was not working because the object created with the alias name was being used as an argument to a stream operator. Here's the simplest possible reproduction code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(std::string const & name) : _name(name) {}
  ~Foo() {}

  std::string _name;
};

std::ostream &
operator<<(std::ostream & o, Foo const & f)
{
  return o << f._name;
}

[[deprecated]] typedef Foo Bar;

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << Foo("one") << " / "
    << Bar("two") << std::endl;

  Foo one("one");
  Bar two("two");

  std::cout << one << " / " << two << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

This is the result of compiling on Apple Clang (notice the warnings for both uses of the alias):
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -o test_deprecation test_deprecation.cpp 
test_deprecation.cpp:25:8: warning: 'Bar' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   25 |     << Bar("two") << std::endl;
      |        ^
test_deprecation.cpp:19:3: note: 'Bar' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
   19 | [[deprecated]] typedef Foo Bar;
      |   ^
test_deprecation.cpp:28:3: warning: 'Bar' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   28 |   Bar two("two");
      |   ^
test_deprecation.cpp:19:3: note: 'Bar' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
   19 | [[deprecated]] typedef Foo Bar;
      |   ^
2 warnings generated.

This is the result on GCC (notice the warning only for the second usage but not the one within the streaming) (and here is a Godbolt link):
$ g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -o test_deprecation test_deprecation.cpp
test_deprecation.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_deprecation.cpp:28:10: warning: ‘Bar’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   28 |   Bar two("two");
      |          ^
test_deprecation.cpp:19:28: note: declared here
   19 | [[deprecated]] typedef Foo Bar;
      |     

And this is the result from MSVC (same as GCC, and here is a Godbolt link):
example.cpp
<source>(28): warning C4996: 'Bar': was declared deprecated
ASM generation compiler returned: 0

I have also tried deprecating a using statement instead of a typedef with the exact same result on all three compilers:
using Bar [[deprecated]] = Foo;

I hate to use the "this is a compiler bug" trope but ... I think this is a compiler bug (really, compilers' bugs). Am I missing something?

I think it is certainly a quality-of-implementation issue, but it is at least not strictly a bug in the sense of standard-conformance. Warning on [[deprecated]] attributes is only a "recommended practice", i.e. not a normative requirement for conformance. However, I think it is relatively clear that the intention of the specification is that any use of the typedef name, other than its own (re-)declaration, should cause a warning. https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.deprecated#4.sentence-1

class [[deprecated]] Bar : public Foo { public: using Foo::Foo; using Foo::operator=; }; could possibly work as a workaround.

@TedLyngmo, I did try that, but in our (much more complicated than the simple example above) use case, the extension class could not be used as an argument to our operator<< implementation, so it did not serve as the backwards-compatibility shim that we intended.

Oh, that's too bad. What's preventing it? Could you add a streaming operator for Bar that just does return o << static_cast<Foo const &>(b); to get around whatever it is that is preventing it from working out-of-the-box?

ADL just having a hard time matching it. We worked around this bug by making the alias be a function named Bar that returns an object Foo. This matches all the use cases that we want to allow to continue working but generate deprecation warnings for.
